# UPDATE table1 where table2 values multiple variables

Tags: sql

Hi I want to update a value in a table called 'fixtures' from `fixtures.toggle=hidden` to `fixtures.toggle=visible`.
It should only update fixtures where `fixtures.compid` is one of the following `competition.id`
in a seperate table called 'competition'.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `competitions` 
WHERE `Year` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '2012' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci 
AND ( `countyid` =4 OR `countyid` =11 OR `countyid` =20 OR `countyid` =22 )
```

I'm pretty new to SQL and would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand, you are looking to update rows having `fixtures.compid` among `competitions.id` returned by your query above. This is probably most easily accomplished using an `IN ()` subquery to return the `competitions.id`:

```
UPDATE
  fixtures
SET toggle = 'visible'
WHERE 
  /* Modify rows currently hidden (not strictly necessary since they would all end up with the same value anyway) */
  toggle = 'hidden'
  /* Retrieve competitions.id matching your criteria */
  AND compid IN (
   SELECT id 
   FROM `competitions` 
   WHERE `Year` LIKE CONVERT( _utf8 '2012' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci 
      /* IN () clause is equivalent to your chain of OR operations */
      AND countyid IN (4, 11, 20, 22)
  )
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Similiar to what I imagined just couldn't get the correct order right in my head.